# fread segmentation fault on local variable

Tags: c, random, segmentation-fault, fread

With the following program I get a segmentation fault when calling fread:

```
static FILE *randomFile = (FILE*)0;
static void myFunction() {
  unsigned char rand;
  unsigned int i;
  [...]
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    //LINE 88 BELOW
    fread(&rand, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, randomFile);
    printf("all well?: %hu\n", (unsigned short) rand);
    [...]
  }
  [...]
}
int main() {
  int i;
  randomFile = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
  if (randomFile == 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  [...]
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    myFunction();
    [...]
  }
  [...]
  fclose(randomFile);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

below is the output of `gdb`'s `run` and `backtrace` commands

```
$ gdb a.out
[...]
(gdb) run
[...]
all well?: 5
all well?: 234
all well?: 9
all well?: 79
all well?: 26
all well?: 108
all well?: 21
all well?: 195
all well?: 192
all well?: 148
all well?: 64
all well?: 211
all well?: 245
all well?: 90
all well?: 173
all well?: 238
all well?: 167
all well?: 125
all well?: 14

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a9ec82 in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a9ec82 in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a96856 in __underflow () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7a945a8 in __GI__IO_file_xsgetn () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7a898e6 in fread () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000400b69 in myFunction ()
    at FileName.c:88
#5  0x0000000000400ebc in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfd8)
    at FileName.c:173
```

I don't see how I could be using the pointers wrong... It's a local variable on the stack which is guranteed to be a valid location with a fixed size...  Especially since it works several times before eventually failing.  What am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MikeCAT verifiable example in progress, I think I found the problem...

Answer (score -1):

apparently the answer has nothing to do with `fread` or the local variable.
My actual code looks more like:

```
static void myFunction() {
  unsigned char rand;
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned short int *buffer1 = malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int)*smallNumberBug);
  unsigned short int *buffer2 = malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int)*smallNumberBug);
  [...]
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    //LINE 88 BELOW
    fread(&rand, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, randomFile);
    printf("all well?: %hu\n", (unsigned short) rand);
    [... modify buffer2 ...]
    memcpy(buffer1, buffer2, sizeof(unsigned short int)*biggerNumber));
  }
  [...]
}
```

somehow writing into improper memory locations resulted in the local stack being... deallocated... not certain how this can be, but changing `smallNumberBug` to be equal to `biggerNumber` solved my problems.